# Custom Application class in Dagger using ActivityIntrumentationTestCase2

Tags: android, testing, dagger

I'm stuck trying to "inject" my custom Application to an ActivityInstrumentationTestCase2.

To be able to make unit tests and injections my Application implements an interface like this:

```
public interface DaggerGraphInjection {
    public ObjectGraph getObjectGraph();
}
```

In the activity i get the graph using:

```
DaggerGraphInjection injector = (DaggerGraphInjection) getApplication();
injector.getObjectGraph().inject(this);
```

Using this kind of interface i'm able to inject mock dependencies in my unit tests. But when i want to run functional tests i get the next exception:

```
10-11 08:57:32.588  17879-17879/? E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.foo.bar/com.foo.bar.activities.MyCalendarActivity}: java.lang.ClassCastException: android.app.Application cannot be cast to com.foo.bar.DaggerGraphInjection
            at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2110)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2135)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$700(ActivityThread.java:140)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1237)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4921)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1027)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:794)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
     Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: android.app.Application cannot be cast to com.foo.bar.DaggerGraphInjection
            at com.foo.bar.activities.MyCalendarActivity.onCreate(MyCalendarActivity.java:47)
            at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5206)
            at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1094)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2074)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2135)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$700(ActivityThread.java:140)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1237)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4921)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1027)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:794)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

That is because, this kind of tests injects the default Application without implements my interface and my question is: Is the any possible solution to this like a custom TestRunner or something like that?

Thank you :)

Comment: i am also facing this kind of exception. but i get exception in the activity where i am trying to get Application's object, like

myApp = ( MyApplication ) LoginActivity.this.getApplication();

Comment: In my case the problem was that i wasn't defining the <application> name to my custom Application class